# React Native Android app crashes while launching with no specific error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, crash, onstart

I am working in a react-native app. Previously the app works fine with no error. Suddenly the app crashes on launch. There is no error on log and i tried `adb logcat`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$zzf;
01-24 17:42:47.566 20134 20134 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0)
01-24 17:42:47.566 20134 20134 E AndroidRuntime:    at co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninModule$1.run(RNGoogleSigninModule.java:120)
01-24 17:42:47.566 20134 20134 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
01-24 17:42:47.566 20134 20134 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 17:42:47.566 20134 20134 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
01-24 17:42:47.566 20134 20134 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
01-24 17:42:47.566 20134 20134 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-24 17:42:47.566 20134 20134 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
01-24 17:42:47.566 20134 20134 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
01-24 17:42:47.566 20134 20134 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zzf" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.thfm-eBstgIMhhMpfYK-WZbNdew==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.thfm-eBstgIMhhMpfYK-WZbNdew==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.thfm-eBstgIMhhMpfYK-WZbNdew==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
01-24 17:42:47.566 20134 20134 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
01-24 17:42:47.566 20134 20134 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
01-24 17:42:47.566 20134 20134 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
01-24 17:42:47.566 20134 20134 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 9 more
01-24 17:42:47.612 20134 20139 I zygote  : Compiler allocated 5MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
01-24 17:42:47.675  3005  3703 D LocationManagerService: getLastLocation: Request[ACCURACY_FINE gps requested=0 fastest=0 num=1]
01-24 17:42:47.677 20134 20202 I ReactNativeJS: [CodePush] App is up to date.


Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zzf" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.thfm-eBstgIMhhMpfYK-WZbNdew==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.thfm-eBstgIMhhMpfYK-WZbNdew==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.thfm-eBstgIMhhMpfYK-WZbNdew==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
```

[image]

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.thfm"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':appcenter-push')
     compile(project(':react-native-device-info')){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-gcm'
    }
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-version-number')
    compile project(':react-native-code-push')
    //compile project(':react-native-sentry')
    compile project(':appcenter')
    compile project(':appcenter-crashes')
    compile project(':appcenter-analytics')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){      
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'

    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

"react": "16.2.0",
"react-native": "0.52.0",
"react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",

I don't what exactly the error is, but above seem to be the cause.

Comment: This is probably a Play Services version conflict. Try upgrading play-services-auth (and probably everything else, otherwise it'll complain) to a more recent version

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?